# SharpSvn 64-bit issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit, sharpsvn

I have installed Tortoise SVN (64bit) on a Windows Server 2008 (64bit) machine and on this machine, I have Visual Studio 2010 installed. I am using VS2010 to build a web application, and in this project I am referencing the SharpSVN dll to perform some SVN task. This dll is 32-bit and is working fine when I run my project locally. However, when I try to publish to IIS then try to run the web application remotely it shows an error regarding SharpSVN. So to resolve this, I changed the reference to SharpSvn 64-bit in the project. Now it's working fine  in the remote case but not locally. So I have to change this dll version each time I switch between working locally or remotely. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tricks you can perform in your web.config or application config file. Another option is installing SharpSvn in your GAC (but I would avoid that).

Comment: Well, enabling 32 bit application, in IIS application pool solved my problem....:)